# JavaScript -- take a picture of a website

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website I want to load an image that is an exact picture of what you would see on your screen if you were scrolled to the top of a target website -- just a snapshot with no functionality behind it.  So if I ran this code with an NY Times article an image of the article's page would be returned.  How do I do this?

Comment: Assuming that you mean to do it on the client side - in Firefox `<canvas>` allows doing this. You can only do it for your own website however, for other websites this is restricted by same-origin policy. Makes sense - imagine that you would make a snapshot of user's online banking session and send it to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [Phantom JS](http://www.phantomjs.org/).  It includes a "render" method that can output a .png image of any rendered web page.  See the "rendering" section of [this phantomjs wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart).